# Installing comtypes 1.1.3-2 but getting 1.1.3 instead

Tags: python, pip, comtypes

I'm trying to install `comtypes` using pip. I specified `1.1.3.post2` as the version number, but pip keeps installing version `1.1.3` instead.

This is the message I get when trying to install it:

```
Requested comtypes==1.1.3.post2 from https://pypi.python.org/packages/85/11/722b9ce6725bf8160bd8aca68b1e61bd9db422ab12dae28daa7defab2cdc/comtypes-1.1.3-2.zip#md5=4161cb8bc283a75af85e220ad662d5af,
but installing version None
```

I'm baffled. I already tried deleting pip cache directory.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for. Please provide a coherent problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the content of comtypes-1.1.3-2.zip is comtypes-1.1.3. So the new version is already installed, but pip mistakenly report the new version as the old ones because of the same name of both version's directory.